# Build a Tree from Flat Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

This is a list that is returned by API and need to convert this to a Tree which can display so a user can select the required permissions.

```
const list = [
{
    resource: 'User',
    action: 'Create',
    id: 1,
},
{
    resource: 'User',
    action: 'Edit',
    id: 2,
},
{
    resource: 'User',
    action: 'Delete',
    id: 3,
},
{
    resource: 'Utility.Rule',
    action: 'Create',
    id: 4,
},
{
    resource: 'Utility.Rule',
    action: 'Edit',
    id: 5,
},
{
    resource: 'Utility.Config',
    action: 'Create',
    id: 6,
},
```

];

And need to get converted to a Tree

```
    {
  "id": "root",
  "name": "MyTree",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "User",
      "name": "User",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Create"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Edit"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Delete"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Utility",
      "name": "Utility",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "Rule",
          "name": "Rule",
          "Children": [
            {
              "id": "4",
              "name": "Create"
            },
            {
              "id": "5",
              "name": "Edit"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "Config",
          "name": "Config",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "6",
              "name": "Create"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried different methods like Map and reduce but not getting desired output.

```
const arrayToTree = (arr, parent = 'User') =>
  arr.filter(item => item.parent === parent)
     .map(child => ({ ...child, children: arrayToTree(arr, 
     child.index) }));

arrayToTree(list, 'User')

//This gives me stackoverflow error.
```

Other option I tried was to build first the map

```
function list_to_tree(list) {
  var map = {}, node, roots = [], i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    map[list[i].id] = i; // initialize the map
    list[i].children = []; // initialize the children
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    node = list[i];
    if (node.parentId !== "0") {
      // if you have dangling branches check that map[node.parentId] exists
      list[map[node.parentId]].children.push(node);
    } else {
      roots.push(node);
    }
  }
  return roots;
}
```

It would be great if I can get some hit how to construct the main node and then add the children.

Comment: What's going-on with the tree structure you've shown? I'm looking at the first 3 children. They all have identical names (Create). Shouldn't they be Create, Edit & Delete? In fact, *all* of the children array elements in your proposed output have the name Create. Could you fix this please, or explain how on earth the tree is supposed to be formed.

Comment: @enhzflep - thanks for pointing out. Yes it is a typo which I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to loop through the list, splitting each resource by '.' and adding a node for each resource directory if not already within the parent node's children

```js
const list = [
    { resource: 'User', action: 'Create', id: 1 },
    { resource: 'User', action: 'Edit', id: 2 },
    { resource: 'User', action: 'Delete', id: 3 },
    { resource: 'Utility.Rule', action: 'Create', id: 4 },
    { resource: 'Utility.Rule', action: 'Edit', id: 5 },
    { resource: 'Utility.Config', action: 'Create', id: 6 },
];

function arrayToTree(list, rootNode = { id: 'root', name: 'MyTree' }) {
    const addChild = (node, child) => ((node.children ?? (node.children = [])).push(child), child);

    for (const { id, action, resource } of list) {
        const path = resource.split('.');
        const node = path.reduce(
            (currentNode, targetNodeId) =>
                currentNode.children?.find(({ id }) => id === targetNodeId) ??
                addChild(currentNode, { id: targetNodeId, name: targetNodeId }),
            rootNode
        );
        addChild(node, { id: String(id), name: action });
    }

    return rootNode;
}

console.log(arrayToTree(list));
```